# R - How to read multiple png files in R and knit into a pdf?

Tags: r, png, knitr

I have around 100 .png files (plots generated earlier in R through another script) that I want to read into R. After reading I want to knit them into one pdf document with 1 or 2 plots in each page. I keep getting errors.

> Error in png::readPNG(path, native = TRUE, info = TRUE) : file is not in PNG format

Comment: Did you consider using `include_graphics(path)` and using `list.files()` to populate `path`? That way you could just include your existing PNG files into a document and then knit to PDF.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already generating the PNG files in R, why not generate them directly in the Rmarkdown document? Set `cache = TRUE` to speed up computation after the first execution of the document.

If you want to include them manually, you should use `knitr::include_graphics()` within a chunk. You can add individual plots to a page with this method, and [from the documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/knitr/man/include_graphics.html) you can pass it a character vector of paths. As suggested by @CL in the comments, you could use `list.files()` to find all your PNGs and create the character vector to pass into the function.

For example you will have a code chunk that would look something like this:

```r
paths <- list.files(path = "path/to/images", pattern = "*.png")
knitr::include_graphics(paths)
```

If you want more control over placement of images, you will need to break this into multiple chunks. Note though that the `pattern` argument of the `list.files()` function takes a regular expression, so you could include files in one chunk that match a pattern (say `a_images1.png`, `a_images2.png`, etc), and then include a different pattern in another chunk.